# React bootstrap table show number of rows

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

How do I show the number of rows in a table using [react bootstrap table](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/index.html).

Additionally, I am using the [search parameter](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#search) to filter the table, so would like the number of rows to update as the table data is filtered.

Comment: Where are you trying to show the length? Inside the table component, in a parent or in a container? The table's state.data changes with filtering, so you could grab the length of that array.

Comment: @ryanabooth i would like to show the row count next to the search bar: http://i.imgur.com/Ytixs6F.png

Comment: do you mean showing the entries 
like a text not the select button i mean a text like this one (Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries) at the left of pagination buttons

Answer (score 0):

Just take the length of the data variable that you are giving  to the data attribute of the BootstrapTable tag

```
<BootstrapTable data = {this.props.data}>


this.props.data.length()
```

this will give you the size of rows